# The tocloft package adds an empty page between list of figures (lof) and Chapter 1

Tags: tocloft, emptypage

I'm using the `tocloft` package in my `book` class document primarily to take care of undesired line breaks and formatting issues in the ToC, LoT, and LoF. The last item in the LoF was alone on a new page, so I used the command (as suggested by the `tocloft` manual):

```
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}}
```

to take to care of the issue. This fixes the problem, however it creates an undesired new empty page in the document. Is there any way to get rid of it?

My document is HUGE, but hopefully this MWE will be sufficient. I'm including all the packages I use, just in case there's any conflicts I'm not thinking of (although I suspect most of them will be irrelevant for this example.:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside, openany]{book}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[%
font={small},
labelfont={bf}]{caption}
%footnotes on tables
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\usepackage{hyphsubst}
\HyphSubstLet{english}{usenglishmax}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[comma,super,sectionbib,sort&compress]{natbib} 
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{(#1)}

\usepackage{titlesec} % For "Chapter" formatting

% Table of Contents
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}


% 
%headers and footers
%
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % formatting not included here. 

\begin{document}
\frenchspacing \raggedbottom

\pagestyle{plain}
\frontmatter


\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\listoftables\clearpage


\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures
\clearpage % this is neccessary, otherwise page style is wrong.

%% ---> This is where the undesired empty page is created. 

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{fancy}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}}
%Chapter 1
\include{chap1}

%Chapter 2
\include{chap2}


%Chapter 3
\include{chap3}


%Chapter 4
\include{chap4}

%Chapter 5
\include{chap5}

%Chapter 6
\include{chap6}
% Inside this chapter, I have the command \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}} 
% In order to adjust the final LoF entry so it's not a widow on a single page (or is it an orphan?!?)....
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated, hyperref should be loaded last and you're missing a `} ` on it.

Comment: Oh, I see. That's just a typo from when I pasted it here. And I think it is. hyperref is on the main .tex file, whereas everything else is on a separate .sty file.